# Complicated identity relating two 2F2 hypergeometric functions

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I would like to relate the following hypergeometric 2F2 function:

$\,_2F_2 \left(1, n+1-\alpha;n+2,n+2-\alpha-\beta;-x\right)$,

where $\alpha,\beta>0$ to another 2F2 function:

$\,_2F_2 \left(n+1,\alpha;n+2,1+\alpha+\beta;x\right)$.

I would be very grateful if someone could help out.

Comment: There is a general transformation for ${}_2F_2$ http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704002237 However, it is not of the type you are looking for.